# No puedo llenar formulario en movil

Tags: html, css, html5, web

Tengo un formulario que funciona perfectamente en pc. Pero en móviles, si bien me aparece el teclado, no puedo escribir en los inputs.

Este es el html:

```
<article>
    <section>
        <h2>Formulario de Contacto</h2>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <p>Los campos marcados con <span>*</span> son obligatorios</p> 
            <h3>Nombre completo<span>*</span></h3>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form__field">
            <h3>Email<span>*</span></h3>
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form__field">
            <h3>Asunto<span>*</span></h3>
            <input type="text" name="subject" class="form__field">
            <h3>Mensaje<span>*</span></h3>
            <textarea id="message-field" name="message" class="form__field"></textarea>
           

            <input type="submit" id="submit-button" name="submit">
        </form>
    </section>

</article>
```

Y este el css:

```
section {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: fit-content;
}

section h2{
  padding-top: 0rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  font-size: 3rem;
}

form{
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

form p{
  padding-bottom: 3rem;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}
form span{
  color: #f00;
}

.form__field{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ddd;
  border-color: #ccc;
  border-style: solid;
  height: 1.5rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  resize: none;
  border-width: 0.1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

#message-field{
  height: 10rem;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}

form h3{
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}


#submit-button{
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 10rem;
  background-color: #0000f0;
  border-color: #45C2E3;
  border-style: solid;
  color: #fff;
  border-width: 0.2rem;
}

#submit-button:hover{
  background-color: #45C2E3;
  border-color: #0000f0;
  color: #000;
}

@media(max-width: 820px) {
  section h2{
    padding-top: 1rem;

  }
}


@media(max-width: 580px) {

  section h2{
    font-size: 2rem;
  }

  form p{
    font-size: 1rem;
  }

  #message-field{
    height: 8rem;
  }

  form h3{
    font-size: 1.1rem;
  }

}
```

Comment: Tienes alguna validación de JQuery, JavaScript en tu código.

Comment: No la tengo. Antes quería solucionar esto

Comment: Lo mas probable es que tu problema este en el css, si lo compartes tal vez pueda ayudarte

Comment: Ya agregué el css.

Comment: Estas usando un dispositivo real para probar el formulario, o lo estas haciendo desde un emulador?, yo lo estoy haciendo desde chrome simulando un mobile y funciona

Comment: Lo estoy haciendo desde un iphone 6

Comment: Probando desde un android con un editor online si me deja rellenar el formulario. Puedes usar el editor del sitio con un imput simple y compararlo con tu codigo para ver si es el so o la version del mavegador.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

miré más arriba que tu problema es con un Iphone (y evidentemente el navegador Safari)

Por ello, solo debes agregar a tu CSS ésto y se solucionará:

```
input {-webkit-user-select: text;}
```

Eso se debe a que en el navegador Safari, `user-select: text` no funciona, por eso necesitamos proporcionar la regla `-webkit-user-select: text` específica del navegador.